# how to proceed credit card ocr

Tags: ocr, credit-card

I'm implementing credit card ocr engine.

My first try was to use opencv for detecting ROI and through the ROI to CNN.
Actually it recognizes quiet well from CNN however, it can not detect ROI well while the card digits are embossed with similar color.

Second try was to adapt YOLO or retinanet for detecting and recognizing.
However, YOLO lasts too many hours for trainig and for retinanet, it can not detect/recognize from credit card. (However it catches number from natural scenes quiet well.)

I dont know how can I implement this.
If you can give me some advise, it would be super thanksful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [credit card OCR](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/17/credit-card-ocr-with-opencv-and-python/)?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I tried but does not work with embossed card like similar background color.

Comment: Any updates on your problem, have you solve it ?